# Influenza/ILI activity by municipality or clinic

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for weekly data on all new cases at the clinic, city, or county level, for all previous flu seasons. Does anyone know where I can find such a dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any definitive source, but this is doable piece-meal I think.
[New York Data starting from 2009-2010](https://healthdata.gov/dataset/influenza-laboratory-confirmed-cases-county-beginning-2009-10-season).
[Google has a lot from FluTrends](https://www.google.org/flutrends/about/).
[Trends in Recorded Influenza Mortality: United States, 1900–2004](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2374803/); I'm assuming datasets are cited/linked to here.

Comment: If I could get a dataset like New York's, that would be ideal. In any case, thank you!